# View does not show results. Angularjs MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fetch records from database using asp.mvc with angular js but i am not able to get records.

I am having Employee Table

[image]

Employee Controller

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SelectData.Models;

namespace SelectData.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult getAll()
        {
            using (EmployeeDBEntities dbContext = new EmployeeDBEntities())
            {
                var employeeList = dbContext.Employees.ToList();
                return View(employeeList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Angular JS module

```
var app = angular.module("AngularApp", []);
```

Angular JS Service

```
app.service("EmployeeService", function ($http) {
    this.getEmployee = function () {
        debugger;
        return $http.get("/employee/getAll");
    };
});
```

Angular JS Controller

```
app.controller("EmpCtrl", function ($scope, EmployeeService) {
    GetAllEmployee();

    function GetAllEmployee() {
        debugger;
        var getAllEmployee = EmployeeService.getEmployee();
        getAllEmployee.then(function (emp) {
            $scope.employees = emp.data;
        }, function () {
            alert('Data not found');
        });
    }
});
```

View

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "getAll";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div ng-controller="EmpCtrl">
    <div>
        <h2 align="center">Angular JS Basic Example</h2>
        <h5 align="center">Employee List</h5>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Employee Id
                </td>
                <td>
                    First Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    Address
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
                <td>
                    {{emp.EmpId}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{emp.FirstName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{emp.LastName}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="AngularApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/angular/Module.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/angular/Service.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/angular/Controller.js"></script> @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>

<body>
    @RenderBody() @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>
```

Data is not shown in the browser , but it shows as json format on browser. Please suggest

[image]

Comment: Check your browser console for any js errors ? Is it making the http call ? Check the network tab. Your code looks fine. Is it returning an array of items  with those properties (`EmpId`)?

Comment: yes it is making http call

Comment: What is being returned from the API?

Comment: not using web api

Comment: So, we can't debug this for you. You'll have to provide details about responses, errors, what ever is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getAll` action  method is returning a view result which is basically html markup (a string). Your should be returning a json array representing your data. Each item in your array should have `EmpId`,`FirstName` and `LastName` properties..

```
public ActionResult getAll()
{
    using (var db = new EmployeeDBEntities())
    {
       var employeeList = db.Employees.Select(f=>new { EmpId =f.EmpId ,
                                                       FirstName = f.FirstName,
                                                       LastName = f.LastName }
                                             ).ToList();
       return Json(employeeList,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Here i am projecting the Employee items to an annonymous object. So the result of `getAll` will be a json array like.

```
[
    {
        "EmpId": 1,
        "FirstName": "Shyju",
        "FirstName": "K"
    }
]
```

Which your angular code will be able to use for the `ng-repeat`

BTW, your markup code should be in another view (other than `getAll.cshtml`) and you should try to access that action method in your browser( May be the index view ?)

Comment: It downloads the json file but not showing data on view

Comment: what you mean it download the file ?Open the browser network tab and see the response of this ajax call. Is it not an array ?

Comment: It downloads getAll.json file which has this data `[{"EmpId":1,"FirstName":"Andy","LastName":"Toe"},{"EmpId":2,"FirstName":"Jessie","LastName":"Ed"},{"EmpId":3,"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Heslop"},{"EmpId":4,"FirstName":"Lucy","LastName":"Stall"}]`

Comment: Try in chrome browser please

Comment: See my modified question. Added Image

Comment: data is shown in the browser whic his correct. Now you need to run your code where it is making the http call and use this data. With your current code it should work fine. What is not working ? BTW, You should have all those view code markup in a view other than the `getAll.cshtml` .`getAll` is your method which returns the data.

Comment: How to make http call to use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122140/discussion-between-shyju-and-user1030181).